# How to share content from my iOS app onto BBM?

Tags: ios, share, bb-messenger

I am trying to allow users of my app to share contents from my apps on their social timelines and within their chat messenger apps. 
Recently I came up with the fact that BBM is actually one of the most common messenger apps in my target countries. Therefore that integration is majorly important in my case.
I found some posts around about the URL scheme of BBM on iOS, however nothing really useful as there is not a sound documentation for it at all. I even wonder whether there is a solution through their API using and SDK or alike.

I am much thankful for any help on this topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke BBM with a draft message for the user to send and this is supported on BBM for iOS, BlackBerry 10 and Android.  I recently wrote a blog post about this on the BlackBerry Developer Blog.  You can find all the details here:

[Cross Platform Sharing with BBM](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2015/02/cross-platform-sharing-with-bbm/)

Comment: could u pls explain what is it mean?